# Replacing NaN Values with another dataframe with pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

am getting a bit stuck on replacing a column of expiry dates for NaN values in one dataframe from another dataframe with different length of indexes.

Sample data df1:

```
    SOH     Price     Value  Expiry  Comments  
0    1P     10.49     10.49     NaN       NaN  
1   220      7.55     16.61     NaN       NaN
```

replace expiry columns with df2:

```
    SOH     Price     Value    Expiry  Comments  
1    1P      6.22      6.22     NaN       NaN  
2    61     17.65     10.77     NaN       NaN  
3    1P     11.99     11.99     NaN       NaN  
4    2P     54.45    108.90     NaN       NaN  
5    1P     10.49     10.49     May-17       NaN  
6   220      7.55     16.61     June-18       NaN
```

So the new dataframe may have different order and indices but columns remain the same.

I'd like to achieve for df1 output to be:
        SOH     Price     Value  Expiry  Comments
    0    1P     10.49     10.49     May-17      NaN
    1   220      7.55     16.61     June18       NaN

Ive tried:

- df1.fillna(df2),
- df1.update(df2)
- df1.loc[df1['Expiry'].isnull(),'Expiry'] =
  df1['Expiry'].map(df2.Expiry)
- forward loops with 3 args,
- merge
- inner join

but  no luck yet :( any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you replacing based on SOH column?

Comment: Nope, I need the price and and value to match in case there are other SOH that appears to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` on `['SOH', 'Price', 'Value']` then `fillna`

```
cols = ['SOH', 'Price', 'Value']
d2 = df2.set_index(cols).Expiry.dropna()
df1.fillna(df1.drop('Expiry', 1).join(d2, on=cols))

   SOH  Price  Value   Expiry Comments
0   1P  10.49  10.49   May-17      NaN
1  220   7.55  16.61  June-18      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but oddly   "d2 = df2.set_index(cols).Expiry.dropna()" gives me AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Expiry'

Comment: Then your column names arent what you think they are

Comment: it appears with the .set_index(cols) my print(d2) becomes: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [105, 22.92, 40.11, nan, nan, etc], any pointers to what i'm doing wrong? Looks like it just set everything into the index with no values in columns

Comment: are you using `cols = ['SOH', 'Price', 'Value']`?  What does print(df2.columns)` say?

Comment: Yup i did as you advised, print(d2.columns) gives: Index(['SOH', 'Price',
       'Value', 'Expiry', 'Comments'],
      dtype='object'), and d1 columns gives the same also

Comment: Ends up im terribad at following instructions. Your instructions work perfectly!